# What happens when I don't cast?

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting a bug that I'm having a hard time recreating consistently. I think it has to do with the fact that I'm not casting an object but I'm not 100% sure.

```
UINavigationController *navController = [self navigationController];
MainGameViewController *controller = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];

controller.phase = @"READY";
```

I know the objectAtIndex:2 will always return an object of type MainGameViewController but could the fact that it's not being cast be the source of inconsistent errors? The error occurs on the 3rd line I've provided.

Here is the trace:

```
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3a6703e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x394fc95e objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3a673f2c -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 180
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3a672648 ___forwarding___ + 388
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3a5ca204 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
5   AppName                     0x0003af56 -[ResultViewController BackToMainGameView] (ResultViewController.m:286)
```

The error occurs in the class ResultsViewController.

Comment: What is the traceback of the error?

Comment: Casting does *not* change the type of an Object (casting primitives is a coercion operation which is different). It only changes the compile time "view"; possibly making it incompatible with the actual Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, casting has nothing to do with the problem. The reason you get an excetion is that sometimes the object at index 2 is of a wrong type. The fact that the error does not happen consistently is an additional clue: look for a situation when the game controller is *not* at the second index to solve this problem.

Generally, casting helps at telling the compiler more about the type of your object. Given the dynamic nature of Objective C, this is a lot less important than, say, in C++.

Comment: This was my initial hunch but I can't think of a situation where objatindex:2 isn't of that type. i'll keep looking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I think it has to do with the fact that I'm not casting an object but I'm not 100% sure.

No. Casting is just for fooling the compiler (in this particular case), the actual class of the object is determined at runtime. The exception occurs because your object does not implement the method it is sent, since it is not of the expected class.

Comment: This makes pefect sense. Thanks.